# Reading binary data from SQL Server CE in C#

Tags: c#, binary, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to read binary data from a SQL Server CE database file.

I tried with this code:

```
string fileName = "C:\\Users\\Luca\\Desktop\\TestNoah\\TestNoah\\NOAHDatabaseCoreSqlCompact.sdf";
connectionString = string.Format("DataSource='{0}'; Persist Security Info=False", fileName);

using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();

    using (SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT PublicData FROM Action",con))
    {
        byte[] barrImg = (byte[])command.ExecuteScalar();

        List<byte> test = barrImg.ToList<byte>();
        string strfn = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());

        FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\Luca\\Desktop\\TestNoah\\TestNoah\\" + strfn + ".jpg" , FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
        fs.Write(barrImg, 0, barrImg.Length);

        fs.Flush();
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

This code creates an image that I can't open. Any ideas? Thanks to all

Comment: This will return `PublicData` for all rows. Isn't there a condition to select ONLY one row? Or can you try `SELECT TOP 1`?

Answer (score 1):

The code below uses the `ExecuteReader` instead of `ExecuteScalar` (which should not be used unless you expect only a single return value from the result set where your SqlCeCommand has a `WHERE` limited by primary key or you have `TOP 1` in your `SELECT`.

```
string targetDir = "C:\\Users\\Luca\\Desktop\\TestNoah\\TestNoah\\";
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    byte[] img = (byte[])reader["PublicData"];
    string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetDir, string.Format("{0}.jpg", DateTime.Now.ToFileTime()));
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, img);
}
```

If you still have image corruption issues, I expect it would be your source data record.

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

Thank you for your reply. unfortunately I still have corruption issues on the image. The source data record is the result of backup procedure of a software. It is correct because when I import backup on software it restore all datas.

Comment: no, I'm not...The dabase (sdf) is the result of a backup procedure and I have no idea what kind of file format it use